# How to search for table by schema before DROP

Tags: sql-server, schema

I'm trying to check if a table exists in a specific schema, before deleting it.

For example :

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'table1')
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE schema1.table1
END
```

Even though DROP specifies the schema, how can I change the `EXISTS` check to include schema1 as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` to `sys.schemas`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM sys.tables t
               JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
           WHERE t.[name] = N'YourTable'
             AND s.[name] = N'YourSchema') BEGIN...
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer using

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('Data.Capture') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Exists'
END
```

as this allows me not just to check for tables , but for any other objects as well while retaining a standard practice for object existence checks